# How to migrate java application form oracle jdk to openjdk?

Tags: java, java-8, jboss

we have one java application which is deployed in jboss application server and using java 1.8.0_202 version, now we want to change it to openjdk.
how can i change?
is there any code changes required?
please help me complete steps to be performed?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: OpenJDK does not provide binary releases.  [adoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) does (there are other choices as well). No code changes should be required (**if** you use a Java 8 release).

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, do i need to generate new .war with the new openjdk , or can i use existing war(which is generated in java 1.8.0_202)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No changes required to your codebase when switching between implementations of Java 8. Java is defined by a set of specifications along with JSRs and JEPs. Any implementation that complies with those specs will run your JBoss app server. Your existing [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) or EAR file will run as-is with no changes needed.

Understand that the OpenJDK project provides an implementation of Java as source code. The OpenJDK project does *not* provide binary builds nor installers.  For builds and installers, you must locate a vendor. You have a choice of several, some free-of-cost and some that require a fee.

Here is a flowchart I made to help you choose a vendor.

This chart is aimed at Java 11, but many of these vendors also supply Java 8. Some, such as Azul Systems, have even back-ported features to Java 8 such as *Flight Recorder*.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]