# Java FX works in command line, but I cannot make it work in any IDE

Tags: java, javafx, ide

I am trying to set up JavaFX library on Windows 10 following the instructions provided here:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

`javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java` works fine with the provided example file.

However running the exact same command does not work with Notepad++ nppexec plugin, which I cannot make sense of. I get the error message: `error: module not found: javafx.controls`
*update: I've realized the command does not work with Windows Powershell either, I gues nppexec must use that.*

I was trying to follow the instructions to set up JavaFX in both NetBeans and IntelliJ, but neither have worked. I get similar error messages e.g. `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`
Tried NetBeans with Ant and Maven Projects.

None of these suggestions have worked:
https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/91

I am using JDK 14.01. and FX 14.01.

PATH_TO_FX is defined, JFX library is added in IDE, I can run projects that do not use JFX. `--module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` VM options are added

---

**Progress with suggested solutions:**

- upgrading to NetBeans 12 from 11.3 did not make any difference. Tried *javafx-archetype-fxml*. The pom file does contain the dependencies, I see them in IDE as well, but still usual error: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`
- Using LibericaJDK *does work* I can compile in both cmd and powershell with using simply `javac HelloFX.java`. Also works well in IntelliJ. Still I would like to understand why other options did not work.

Comment: Download and install Netbeans 12 and choose one of the JavaFX with maven archetypes.

Comment: Make your life easier and install the [Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/).

Comment: Hello @ElliottFrisch. What are some of the advantages over OpenJDK?

Comment: It's also a release of OpenJDK, but they include LibericaFX with the base install. So no need to manually add JFX. That's why I like it anyway.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks! I went to the site and couldn't find out the advantages.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61497465/2970947).

Comment: Powershell does not use the `%varname%` syntax; iirc in your case you'd need to use `$env:PATH_TO_FX`